# How can I apply the merge sort algorithm to the "List<IntPoint>" in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a code for the merge algorithm but codes are written for arrays all the time. How can I use the merge algorithm for the

`List<IntPoint>` in C#(I do not want to put the values in the
`List<IntPoint>` to an array for not to lose time)?

Here is the code:

```
class MergeSort
{
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AForge;

namespace blobdnm
{
    class MergeSort
    {
        private int arraySize;
        private List<IntPoint> array;

        //takes in array and area of the array that is populated
        public PointComparer(List<IntPoint> array, int length)//in here the error is:Non-invocable member 'MergeSort.PointComparer' cannot be used like a method.
        {
            this.arraySize = length;
            this.array = array;
            //mergesort is called from the constructor
            MergeSort_Recursive(this.array, 0, arraySize - 1);
        }

        public void DoMerge(List<IntPoint> numbers, int left, int mid, int right)
        {
            List<IntPoint> temp = new IntPoint[arraySize];//Can not implicitly convert type...
            int i, left_end, num_elements, tmp_pos;

            left_end = (mid - 1);
            tmp_pos = left;
            num_elements = (right - left + 1);

            while ((left <= left_end) && (mid <= right))
            {
                if (numbers[left].Compare(numbers[mid]) <= 0)
                    temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[left++];
                else
                    temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[mid++];
            }

            while (left <= left_end)
                temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[left++];

            while (mid <= right)
                temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[mid++];

            for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
            {
                numbers[right] = temp[right];
                right--;
            }
        }

        public class PointComparer : IComparer<IntPoint>
        {
            public static readonly PointComparer Instance = new PointComparer();
            public int Compare(IntPoint a, IntPoint b)//int point does not contain a definition for "Compare"...
            {
                var c = a.X.CompareTo(b.X);
                if (c == 0) return a.Y.CompareTo(b.Y);
                return c;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you simply use `IList<IComparable>` instead of `IComparable[]`, it will work the same.

Comment: Thank you I am gonna try that.@41686d6564 stands w. Palestine

Comment: A list the size cannot be preset like in array new IComparable[arraySize];  So you will need to add members like From: temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[left++]; To : temp.Add(numbers[left++]);

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I asked the question wrongly because of my distraction.I am gonna edit the question.Can I write this algorithm for List<IntPoint>(which is used in Aforge)?If you know and answer the question I would be appreciate it.@jdweng

Comment: "not to lose time" - If you want performance you should probably use the built in sort. The reasons for using a custom implementation is either for learning, or if you have some special knowledge about your situation that you can exploit for improved performance.

Comment: Sorry about my english but I could not understand what you mean correctly.To explain what I want to do.I add aforge graham scan dll to the visual studio and I want to make it faster.I noticed that there is a function for sorting the points and when I look at that I saw that sort function is not dependent to aforge.It is exist in C# library end I want to make the sorting faster.Is that possible@ JonasH

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort points you should start by using the built in sort, i.e. [`List<T>.Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-6.0). For this you will probably need a custom comparator:

```
public class PointComparer : IComparer<IntPoint>
{
    public static readonly PointComparer Instance = new PointComparer();
    public int Compare(IntPoint a, IntPoint b)
    {
        var c = a.X.CompareTo(b.X);
        if (c == 0) return a.Y.CompareTo(b.Y);
        return c;
    }
}
...
myPoints.Sort(PointComparer.Instance);
```

This will *probably* be faster than any custom sorting since it is coded by professionals with intimate knowledge about the CLR and optimizations.

But when working with 2D data it is often quite limiting to sort the data in a single dimension. It is often better to use some kind of spatial data structure like a KD-tree or a quadtree. But that is a much larger change that require your algorithm to support such a structure.

And whenever we are discussing performance, and important point is to *measure*. I.e. you should use a profiler to check where the slowest operations are, and see if you could improve them. An operation like copying points between a list and array should usually not take any significant amount of time, and there is no point optimizing things that are already fast. When things are "slow", a common reason is that something is recomputed unnecessarily, usually because the developer did not realize, or did not care, that the code is inefficient.

At a last point I would consider switching libraries. AForge is quite old, and I do not think it is maintained any more. I have used [MiConvexHull](https://github.com/DesignEngrLab/MIConvexHull) to compute convex hulls, and it seem to work well. But you might want to visit https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ for recommendations.

Comment: Thank you so much for ypur answer.This explanation really comprehensive.I am gonna research the things that you mentioned but as I understood the code you wrote above makes the code worked.I added that to the code but I am still getting error.I am gonna edit the code here.Do you have anything about how I can fix it.Also is MiConvexHull paid when it is used for a project?@JonasH

Comment: @stck_w It is kind of difficult to provide any help when I have no idea what kind of error you are getting

Comment: You are right.3 error is exist I am gonna edit the code again.@ JonasH